# Set containment between the images of disks under two analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

$D=D(0,1)$

$f,g: D \to G$ analytic

$f$ is $1-1$

$f(D) = G$

$f(0)=g(0)$

> Then $\forall 0<r<1, g(D(0,r)) \subset f(D(0,r))$

I feel like I am not using any of the assumptions excepts $f(D) = G$ in this proof namely, let $w \in g(D(0,r)) \Rightarrow w = g(\alpha)$. Since $f(D) = G, \exists \gamma \in D$ such that $f(\gamma) = g(\alpha) = w \Rightarrow g(D(0,r)) \subset f(D(0,r))$.

Something has to be wrong here..

Comment: So far, you have no reason to believe that $\lvert\gamma\rvert < r$. Note that $D(0,r) \subsetneqq D$.

Comment: However, there must be an additional hypothesis, otherwise we could give counterexamples. Is there maybe an assumption that $f$ shall be biholomorphic?

Comment: OKay,s o I guess it would be okay if I broke this up into two cases. The first is done above with the assumption that I overlooked, now I just need to do one when $|\gamma|>r$?

Comment: Ah, f is one-to-one as well, sorry

Comment: Consider $f^{-1}\circ g$. And listen to Hermann Amandus.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out thanks! Use that function with Schwarz lemma and 3 more lines and the proof is done.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is the proof of this result (which, by the way, generalizes several exercises already posted here):

1. Let $h=f^{-1}\circ g$; this is a holomorphic map of $D$ into $D$.
2. Observe that $h(0)=0$.
3. By the Schwarz lemma, $h(D(0,r))\subset D(0,r)$ for all $r\in (0,1)$.
4. Hence, $g(D(0,r)) = (f\circ h)(D(0,r)) = f\bigl(h(D(0,r))\bigr) \subset f(D(0,r))$.